# How to loop this code through multiple folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

This code retrieves all the names of files that are larger then a declared size in a folder, but now I want to loop it through multiple folders. How can I do this?

```
(FOR %%f IN (*.jpg)DO @IF %%~zf GTR 40000 ECHO %%f; )> myfiles.txt
```

Comment: `for /r` recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use recursive

```
FOR /R %%f IN (*.jpg) DO @IF %%~zf GTR 40000 ECHO %%f; )> myfiles.txt
```

Comment: when I use this it also shows the path to the image but i only want the file name how can I do this?

Comment: @Mylan well, if you want to do recursive search in all directories, showing the path makes sense. What if you have duplicate file names which you will repeat in a text file, but you're unsure where they are?